# Using netplan to setup a shared connection

Tags: network-manager, netplan

Is it possible to set up a shared connection (DHCP server) on an interface using just the netplan configuration? I can use NetworkManager as follows to set up a shared connection:

```
sudo nmcli c add con-name <name> type ethernet ifname <iface> ipv4.method shared ipv6.method ignore ipv4.addresses <ip>
```

However, I was wondering if I could do this through the netplan yaml file and I wouldn't have to do it manually.

Another requirement I have is to be able to switch the interface to be a DHCP client or DHCP server, for example, when user presses a button. So is this kind of configuration possible to setup through netplan, or do I just have to manually change the interface to be a DHCP client vs server using nmcli.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  Netplan restricts itself to managing the network and DNS configuration of the host that it is running on; configuring and launching additional services such as a DHCP server is out of scope for the present design.  If you need this functionality from NetworkManager, you should manage it directly through NM using `nmcli` or the like as above, not using netplan.

Alternatively, you *can* manage the network configuration with netplan and manually configure a DHCP server and configure iptables (or nftables) for NAT; but if your expectation is a push-button solution like the NetworkManager option, this will be a disappointing experience.